# Where can i get tiger os 10.4.x?

Tags: imac, data-transfer, macos

I have an old iMac G5 and want to install the original OS on it but can't seem to find the original disks.

Is there a good source to legitimately obtain copies of older Apple operating systems?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot download it anywhere legally. If you lost your installation medium you can request a new one from Apple which will cost around $20 IIRC.

Answer (score 1):

You can also purchase a retail box of OSX 10.4 Tiger from many third parties ( eBay still has quite a few really cheap)

The install won't have all the software such as iLife and games that was bundled with your iMac originally however for some that will be a bonus.